# JDBC - How to insert a string value

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

When trying to insert the value of a string into my db using JDBC instead of inserting the String's value it inserts the String's name.

I have a string named firstName, the value of this string is given by user input.

Here is my sql statement:

```
String sql = "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName, address) VALUES ('124','+firstName()','123')";
```

Comment: You appear not to understand the difference between things inside double quotes vs. outside. It's doing *exactly* what you are telling it to.

Answer (score 6):

For various reasons, it is better to use `java.sql.PreparedStatement`. to execute statements with parameters. For example, if you want to avoid [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

See the examples in [*Using Prepared Statements*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) from [*The Java Tutorials*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/index.html).

The advantage of using SQL statements that take parameters is that you can use the same statement and supply it with different values each time you execute it.

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(
   "UPDATE EMPLOYEES SET FIRST_NAME= ? WHERE ID = ?");

pstmt.setString(1, "user1080390"); // set parameter 1 (FIRST_NAME)
pstmt.setInt(2, 101); // set parameter 2 (ID)

int rows = pstmt.executeUpdate(); // "rows" save the affected rows
```

Comment: I'll be sure to read up on PreparedStatement's in the coming weeks. Unfortunately , and I know this sounds bad; I haven't the time right at this moment, I have to meet a deadline for tommorow. Is there any chance you could be more specific?

Comment: The time you spend trying out dirty hacks could be spent reading up PreparedStatments and using it. Paul's code snippet should be enough to get you going.

Comment: I tried to modify the prepared insert statement from this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1073101/how-do-you-do-an-extended-insert-using-jdbc-without-building-strings But I received the error: Cannot find symbol preparedstatement ...

Comment: Be sure to properly import the necessary classes. Perhaps `import java.sql.*;` might suffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`String sql = "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName, address) VALUES ('124','"+firstName()+"','123')";`

To prevent sql injections, you need to escape the string before using in a query or try the prepared statements.

Comment: This is the dirty and dangerous way, error prone (what if firstName contains quotes?), and, above all, has the danger of SQL injection attacks. Never do this in real code.

Comment: Provider.java:90: cannot find symbol symbol : method firstName() localtion: class Provider String sql = "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName, address) Values ('124','"+firstName()+"','123')";                                              ^

Answer (score 0):

Something like this..

```
String firstName ="sample";
String sql = "Insert INTO users (ID, firstName, address) VALUES ('124',"+firstName+",'123')";
```